# Crytek Sponza bugs

Tags: 3d, textures

I downloaded `sponza_obj.rar` (`sponza.obj` + `sponza.mtl`) and `sponza_textures.rar` from the Crytek site. It looks like that there is lack of `gi_flag.tga`. Where I can find the missing texture ? Moreover the texture pack contains many specular texutres but `.mtl` file doesn't have paths for them. Why ? Next the brick material has following record: 
`map_bump textures\spnza_bricks_a_diff.tga` It make no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid Crytek Sponza package is available here: http://casual-effects.com/data/index.html
All required textures are in-place.